# GCP Managed SSL Certificate stuck on FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've followed [GCP's guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs) to creating a managed SSL certificate for my subdomain `<subdomain>.<domain>.dev`.

My domain registrar is configured with the NS records:

```
    ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.
    ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com.
    ns-cloud-d3.googledomains.com.
    ns-cloud-d4.googledomains.com.
```

My GCP project is managing the domain name using Cloud DNS with the following entries:

```
<domain>.dev.   MX  3600    

    10 eforward1.registrar-servers.com.
    10 eforward2.registrar-servers.com.
    10 eforward3.registrar-servers.com.
    15 eforward4.registrar-servers.com.
    20 eforward5.registrar-servers.com.


<domain>.dev.   NS  21600   

    ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.
    ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com.
    ns-cloud-d3.googledomains.com.
    ns-cloud-d4.googledomains.com.


<domain>.dev.   SOA     3601    

    ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com. <mail>. 2019032900 86400 7200 3600000 3601


<domain>.dev.   TXT     3600    

    "v=spf1" "include:spf.efwd.registrar-servers.com" "~all"


<subdomain>.<domain>.dev.   A   7200    

    <ingress-ip>


www.<domain>.dev.   CNAME   1799    

    <domain>.dev.
```

Pinging `<subdomain>.<domain>.dev` resolves the expected IP of the target Ingress, and making requests to the application at `http://<subdomain>.<domain>.dev` works correctly.

So why does managed certificate provisioning fail with `FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was referencing the wrong name of the static IP resource in Ingress.

When creating the Ingress, a new global static IP was created. For some reason it was created with an autogenerated name like `k8s-fw-myapp-myapp-api--3b52739e6d618a1f`, rather than the human readable name that I have assigned to it.

Changing the Ingress annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name` to the autogenerated name fixed the issue.